Call function in Python script in a Gitlab repositry from another script in another Gitlab repository
I have two Gitlab repositories that are both private and on an internal server. The first repo (let's call this Repo A) contains a Python script with some general functions. The second repo (Repo B) contains multiple Python scripts that are developed by the users. Calling a function in another Python script can easily be done by importing the script and then call the function, but I don't know if this is possible when the scripts are in two different repo's.
Is there a way to call a function in the Python script in Repo A, using a Python script in Repo B?

Import modules from both repos? I assume that by 'importing the script' you mean 'downloading and installing the package that contains the module into your environment and importing it' - there's no reason a script couldn't do that for modules from multiple repos, provided that it's set up correctly. What exactly is your question? What does your actual setup look like to prompt your question?

By 'importing the script' I literally mean the code line 'Import script_name' (when everything is set locally and the scripts are in the same folder). The question is: now these two scripts are placed in Gitlab in two different repo's, so how to do it then?

You're confusing two things. When you import a module in Python, it has to be found in the environment your script is running it. For a script sitting in the same folder, this is automatically the case, so that works (providing you've downloaded them from GitLab of course - you can't run your code there).
Take NumPy for example. Even though you can say something like import numpy, your environment will receive the appropriate version built for your operating system and for your CPU architecture, if the package requires some binaries - or your package manager will try to build it when you install it.
And when you install a package, you pick a specific version, which will be the implied version you're loading when you import numpy. Some packages are 'pure Python', and don't need building of binaries, but all packages are versioned.
So, when you import a package, it's coming from your environment. When you install a package, it is made part of your environment, and it's coming from some repository. This can be PyPI (for pip), or Anaconda or Condaforge (for conda), or other sources that such tools support - like remote Git repos on GitLab.
With pip you can install packages directly from Git, using a command like pip install git+https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-paypal.git@issue/34/oscar-0.6 (this is just some answer from another popular SO question). Instead of downloading from a repo that only has Python packages (prebuilt or source), this will download a specific version of the contents of the repo (source), expecting it to be structured like a Python package, ready to build and install.
Of course you could just download a file from GitLab from your script, and eval the code inside it - but this is a spectacularly bad idea, and not directly supported by Python. You'll be writing your own plumbing.
To use a module from some package in another package, you would either add the one package to the requirements of the other package (and this can be a Git URL), or you install both packages to your project as a requirement, and have access to both of them (after installation of the requirements of course).
